# Algorithmic efficiency of dropping a multitude of rows from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, drop

I have a large dataframe out of which I have identified index ranges which I want to drop.

To identify the correct rows I have an array that looks somewhat like this:

```
drop_pairs = [
["2020-01-01 10:00:00","2020-01-03 13:00:00"],
["2020-01-13 11:00:00","2020-01-13 13:33:00"],
["2020-01-22 00:07:00","2020-01-22 22:22:00"],
...]
```

And I'm trying to drop rows in my dataframe based on this array using:

```
for timerange in drop_pairs:
    df = df.drop(df.loc[f"{timerange[0]}":f"{timerange[1]}"].index)
```

But this method really is awfully slow with a large dataframe.
How can I make this more efficient?

Comment: just an idea and I have not tried this with big df, maybe do this on the index first, and then use `loc` to get the `df` you want instead of operating on the big dataframe?

Comment: Part of the problem is that you don't have an array. If you did, you could convert the whole array into a boolean mask pretty trivially, and just subset that way.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted in the comments, this can also be done using boolean arrays. I've converted the array `drop_pairs` into two arrays `drop_starts` and `drop_ends` with the corresponding start and end values of the timeranges to be dropped.

Next, I've created masks:

```
mask_starts = df.index.isin(drop_starts).astype(int)
mask_ends = df.index.isin(drop_ends).astype(int) * -1
```

So that `mask_starts + mask_ends` would give an array the length of my `df` with 1s where a timerange to be dropped starts, -1s where it ends, and 0s everywhere else.

I used `np.cumsum` to subsequently mark all the timestamps to be dropped with 1 and everything else with 0.

```
drop_mask = np.cumsum(mask_starts + mask_ends)
```

Based on this mask, it is easy to drop the concerning ranges:

```
df = df[~drop_mask.astype(bool)]
```